# How to convert INSTANT time UTC toEpochMilli in specific timeZone

Tags: kotlin, time, timezone, utc, instant

Edit: sorry, maybe my question was not correct....

I am trying to convert UTC timestamp to LOCAL timestamp in Java(Kotlin)

f. exm.

UTC time 18:00 Local Germany time is 20:00 I need local germany time in UTC timestamp.....

```
    fun getLocalizedTime(locationId: Long, utcTimeInMs: Long? ): Long{
        val instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(utcTimeInMs?:Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
        val zoneIdAsString = locationDataService.locationData.locations[locationId]?.timeZone
                ?: "UTC"
        val zoneId = ZoneId.of(zoneIdAsString)
        val zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId)

        return instant.atZone(zoneId).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
    }
}
```

returns UTC time:(

How to convert INSTANT time UTC toEpochMilli in specific timeZone

Answer (score 7):

## Epoch milliseconds is in UTC

There is no such thing as “toEpochMilli in specific timeZone”, not if you are going by conventional definitions. The count of milliseconds from epoch reference is always UTC.

A count of milliseconds from an epoch is done in UTC. The epoch reference used by *java.time* and by Unix/POSIX, is the first moment of 1970 *in UTC*, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. The `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced “Zulu”. By the day, dozens of other epoch references are used by various information systems.

So it makes no sense to say “epoch milli in a time zone”.

If you have a count of milliseconds since first moment of 1970 in UTC, parse as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( milliseconds ) ;
```

To see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a specific region, adjust into a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

The `Instant` and the `ZonedDateTime` both represent the **same simultaneous moment**, the same point on the timeline, the same count of milliseconds since epoch reference.

You can extract a `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime` to get back to that original count-from-epoch.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

You will find that the `milliseconds` and `millisecondsSinceEpoch` long integers are the same number.

Your code `instant.atZone(zoneId).toInstant()` does not make sense. You start with an `Instant`, convert to a `ZonedDateTime`, then convert back to an `Instant`. All three objects represent the very same moment, the same count of milliseconds since the epoch reference. Those calls of yours did not accomplish any useful work.

## Germany time to UTC

On further clarification, you said:

> I need local germany time in UTC timestam

Define your specific time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
```

Capture the current moment as seen there.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Adjust to UTC by extracting a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Interrogate for a count of milliseconds, if absolutely needed.

```
long milliseconds = instant.toEpochMilli() ;  // Beware of data loss, as any microseconds/nanoseconds are ignored.
```

I do *not* recommend communicating moments as a count-from-epoch as the resolution (milliseconds versus whole seconds versus microseconds versus nanoseconds versus something else) is not obvious, nor is the epoch reference obvious. Instead, communicate moments as text, in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing text. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

If you want only milliseconds, truncate any existing microseconds or nanoseconds.

```
    String output = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS ).toString() ;  // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/qfFmMW).

> zdt.toString(): 2020-05-09T23:57:35.363701+02:00[Europe/Berlin]
>
> instant.toString(): 2020-05-09T21:57:35.363701Z
>
> milliseconds: 1589061455363
>
> output: 2020-05-09T21:57:35.363Z

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Comment: 0


sorry, may be my question was not correct....

I am traiing to convert UTC timestamp to LOCAL timestamp in Java(Kotlin)

f. exm.

UTC time 18:00 Local Germany time is 20:00 I need local germany time in UTC timestamp.....

Comment: @DimitriRubinsteinTSS Be careful with the word "local". In *java.time*, the word "local" in  the class names means *any* or *all* localities, but not any one particular locality. The `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `LocalDateTime` classes purposely lack any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

Comment: @DimitriRubinsteinTSS Please edit your Question to more clearly state your problem and goal. This page may be read by thousands of people over the years ahead.

Comment: @DimitriRubinsteinTSS In the future, search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. All of this has been covered many times already.